# How can I determine the return type of a C++11 member function

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I am trying to determine the return type of a various C++ member functions. I understand that decltype and std::declval can be used to do this, but I am having problems with the syntax and finding useful examples. The `TestCBClass` below shows an example of a dumb class that contains a mixture static and normal member functions - with & without arguments and return types.  Depending on the method in question, I would like to be able to declare a vector of return types from each of the various methods.

In my application, these methods are callbacks for `std::async` and I need a vector of `std::future<return types>`.  I've tried various declarations such as `decltype(std::declval(TestCBClass::testStaticMethod))` (I'm not sure if I need an `&` before the method name).   This syntax is incorrect - and of course it does not compile, but I think its the approach that should be used.

```
class TestCBClass {
public:
    TestCBClass(const int& rValue = 1)
        : mValue(rValue) {
        std::cout << "~TestCBClass()" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~TestCBClass() {
        std::cout << "~TestCBClass()" << std::endl;
    }
    void testCBEmpty(void) {
        std::cout << "testCBEmpty()" << std::endl;
    }
    int testCBArgRet(const int& rArg) {
        std::cout << "testCBArgRet(" << rArg << ")" << std::endl;
        mValue = rArg;
    }
    static void testCBEmptyStatic(void) {
        std::cout << "testCBEmptyStatic()" << std::endl;
    }
    static void cbArgRetStatic(const SLDBConfigParams& rParams) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(gMutexGuard);
        std::cout << rParams.mPriority << std::endl;
    }
    static std::string testStaticMethod(const PriorityLevel& rPrty) {
        return "this is a silly return string";
    }
private:
    int mValue;
};
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You may also use `std::result_of` and `decltype`, if you prefer to list arguments types rather than the corresponding dummy values, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct foo {
  int    memfun1(int a) const { return a;   }
  double memfun2(double b) const { return b; }
};

int main() {
  std::result_of<decltype(&foo::memfun1)(foo, int)>::type i = 10;
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  std::result_of<decltype(&foo::memfun2)(foo, double)>::type d = 12.9;
  std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

[DEMO here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a1540b311ecfce6)

Comment: Since C++17, we should use [`std::invoke_result` instead of `std::result_of`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of). But [the 101010's way](/a/26107152) seems to be more universal anyway, as it allows to deal with overloaded functions.

Answer (score 15):

> *How can I determine the return type of a C++11 member function?*

**Answer:**

You could use `decltype` and `std::declval` like the toy example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct foo {
  int    memfun1(int a) const { return a;   }
  double memfun2(double b) const { return b; }
};

int main() {
  decltype(std::declval<foo>().memfun1(1)) i = 10;
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  decltype(std::declval<foo>().memfun2(10.0)) d = 12.9;
  std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f386de9e23df3db3)

Comment: Thanks, what happens if the memfun1() or memfun2() take arguments - in my case my testStaticMethod takes a PriorityLevel object - which is not default constructible - I think that is what declval is for right?  Also one other thing I forgot to ask in my question - is it possible to print out the type as a string?

Comment: @johnco3 you just put some dummy input arguments. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @johnco3 Yeap `declval` ensures that the constructor of the object is not going to be evoked. You could use [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) to get a string with the type. Better of you could use `type_traits` and in particular [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) to check whether a type is the same with another one.

Comment: I checked your answer as useful, but you probably got my reply as I was also editing it :) unfortunately my argument type is not easy to create with dummy values, is there some way to apply the declval to the arguments also - as I understand from reading the declval documentation that they "Convert any type T to a reference type, making it possible to use member functions in decltype expressions without the need to go through constructors" - I was hoping to avoid the whole construct a dummy thing for my arguments also

Comment: @johnco3 I was going to propose [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) but there's already an answer with this. I also like Piotr's answer you can choose what ever suits you best.

Answer (score 11):

> *I've tried various declarations such as decltype(std::declval(TestCBClass::testStaticMethod))*

You **don't have to use** `std::declval` and pass *actual arguments*, not even *their types*, just to know what is the return type of a static/non-static member function. Instead, you can write your own trait to know what is the return type of a given function:

```
template <typename T>
struct return_type;
template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(*)(Args...)> { using type = R; };
template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...)> { using type = R; };
template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const> { using type = R; };
template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile> { using type = R; };
template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile> { using type = R; };
template <typename T>
using return_type_t = typename return_type<T>::type;

...

TestCBClass t;

std::future<return_type_t<decltype(&TestCBClass::testCBArgRet)>> a =
        std::async(&TestCBClass::testCBArgRet, t, 1);

std::future<return_type_t<decltype(&TestCBClass::testCBEmpty)>> b =
        std::async(&TestCBClass::testCBEmpty, t);

std::future<return_type_t<decltype(&TestCBClass::testCBEmptyStatic)>> c =
        std::async(&TestCBClass::testCBEmptyStatic);
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fa2bf05b5663a97)

Comment: Very nice - and it works (god knows why ;)) type traits are not my thing - although the std::result_of seems a lot simpler and easier to use with the template machinery all hidden under the covers.  Checked answer as useful

Comment: @johnco3: if you like repeating function parameters' types each time you declare `std::future` then yes, you can go with `std::result_of`

Comment: For more complete and/or third party solution there is: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/callable_traits/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Latest syntax to deduce return type **at compile time** is like this:

```cpp
std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&Presenter::present), Presenter, QSqlQuery &> someVariable;
```

Let's consider an example, that you want to construct an object with a default value, eg. `QVector<int>()`, but you need to deduce this type from template parameter, in our example is template parameter `Presenter` and we need to deduce return type for a class method with one parameter `Presenter::present(QSqlQuery &)`:

```cpp
template<typename Presenter>
inline auto defaultReturnValue() const
{
    return std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&Presenter::present), Presenter, QSqlQuery &>();
}
```

The above code deduces the return type for this class:

```cpp
class VectorPresenter final
{
public:
    QVector<int> present(QSqlQuery &query) const;
};
```

Finally, you will call:

```cpp
const auto defaultValue = defaultReturnValue<VectorPresenter>();
```

The result will be the `QVector<int>` instance in the `defaultValue` variable.
And now, you can create a presenter class, which will return **any** type and you will be able to deduce this type. ✨

Comment: This wont work for an overloaded method, how do you specify a method via its argument types?

Comment: If I understand your question right then you would have to pass these argument types as the parameter pack to the `defaultReturnValue()` and then unpack this parameter pack into the `std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&Presenter::present), Presenter, Args...>`.