# Resolving template member function overload

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I'm trying to write template class that inherits from `T` and to correctly implement one part, I need to know what data type is this `T` working with. Fortunately, all valid substitutions for T have member method `GetOutput` which returns the expected data type. However, the method have two overloads: `GetOutput()` and `GetOutput(int)`. I was trying to extract the type using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107041/how-can-i-determine-the-return-type-of-a-c11-member-function) but am failing to get the overload resolution working:

`using OutputType = typename std::result_of<decltype(&T::GetOutput)(T)>::type;`

Is what I'm trying possible and if so, what is the correct way to get there?

Comment: `GetOutput(int)` and `decltype(&T::GetOutput)(T)`. why passing `T`if you expect `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two overloads of `GetOutput` return the same type, you could just pick one of them and use its return type:

```
using OutputType = decltype(std::declval<T&>().GetOutput());
```

Comment: maybe worth noting that `std::result_of` is deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20

Comment: Perfect, didn't occur to me. Also thanks @idclev463035818 for pointing out that piece of info.